# Incremental combo box/text box for ASP.Net MVC page?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a large list of items to be placed in a dropdownlist (>1000) and am trying to figure out a way to create some sort of incremental selectlist or dropdownlist that makes json callbacks to the data source so that the page loads quicker.

I assume that I would use a combo box but i am not sure how to not load the full data set when the page builds.

I'm thinking that using the autocomplete Jquery plugin might be part of the solution.
There is also the fact that I will be loading an existing record into the form that may already ahve a selected item that is in the DDL.

Any tutorials/examples that anyone is aware of?

Answer (score 1):

I would definetly use an autocomplete like [typeahead](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/), that would be faster and easier for your user.

If not then you will need to do a [SetInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) to do a call to an [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method that will return 20 results and add it to the ddl.

Let me know where you need more help and show us what you got so far and I'll do my best to help you.